# Why is the name 'Beauregard' used so often?

Tags: names

In a lot of TV shows, the name 'Beauregard' is used, is it a coincidence or is there some reason for it?

Recently, it has been used again in 'American Horror Story' for the disfigured kid in the attic and also in the new show 'Alcatraz' for the Dr.

Comment: For one thing, it's sexy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a cool name, that means roughly "good looking", so is a fun name to use for ugly-as-sin baddies. It also has the sound of being a good family from foreign parts ( not necessarily France ).

I recall the first time I heard it was "A series of unfortuante events", where is captured the aristocratic-fallen-on-hard-times family situation very well.

Comment: *Beauregard* is made up of *beau* (=beautiful) and *regard* (=look).  It is evocative of beautify eyes or a beautify gaze more than good looks.

Comment: The protagonists in *A Series of Unfortunate Events* were the Baudelaires, not the Beauregards.

Comment: @jwodder - You are right. But the sound of the name has the same sort of evocative sense, and I think the principle applies. I am trying to remember now where I first heard it, because it normally does work well.

Comment: @SchroedingersCat: Sticking with the children's books theme, did you perhaps first hear it in [*Charlie and the Chocolate Factory?*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violet_Beauregarde)

Comment: @jwodder - may well be right. Where, again, the name is important.

Comment: Pierre Gustave Toutant-Beauregard was a very well known and well regarded Civil War General. Thus in Southern circles the name became fairly common.